# pytorch Dataset class __getitem__() not being called

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorflow-datasets, generative-adversarial-network, torchvision

I have this code where I am testing to see if the getitem() method is called when i instantiate this class but it doesn't seem like it is being called! (My program isnt printing GET!)

```
class MaleFacesDataset(Dataset):

 def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir):
    
    self.landmarks_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    self.root_dir = root_dir
    self.transform = transform

 def __len__(self):
    return len(self.landmarks_frame)


 def __getitem__(self, idx):

    print("GET!")

    if torch.is_tensor(idx):
        idx = idx.tolist()


    img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,
                            self.landmarks_frame.iloc[idx, 0])

    image = io.imread(img_name)
    sample = image

    sample = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(sample)).convert('RGB')
    sample = Image.fromarray(sample.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')

    if self.transform:
        sample = self.transform(sample)

    return sample
```

Not sure why! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `__getitem__()` is being called by the Sampler class. In other words, once you set the data loader with some Sampler, the data loader will be an iterable variable. When you access an element within the iterable variable for every mini-batch, `__getitem__()` will be called the number of times your mini-batch is set.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now! Thanks! :)